# How to insert Font Awesome in the text value="my text"?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, input, onclick, font-awesome, reload

I have a button on my offline page that refreshes the page.

Here is his code :

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-success" value="Actualiser la page" onClick="document.location.reload(true)">
```

How to display an Awesome Font logo below, before the text :

```
<i class="fas fa-redo fa-lg"></i>
```

Comment: You can use a button element
`<button class="fas fa-redo fa-lg">Actualiser la page</button>`, if you want to change the icon select `button:before {}`

Comment: @Skylark thank you but you did not add my code to refresh the page. Will it work with button tags ?

Comment: Yes, you can copy across the other attributes, and `onClick` will still work